# Invented Language with Noncontradictory Grammar

Tags: constructed-language

A while back I came across some very recently invented language that aim to have a simple, uniform, non-contradictory grammar, but I have completely forgotten the name. It's not Esperanto. I'm sorry I can't provide much more details, but I did try searching online for various keywords without any luck.

Comment: I see no reason to close this question: Despite the vagueness of the description, the conlang(s) wanted are easily indentifyable, as the accepted answer shows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose what you mean by "non-contradictory grammar" falls under the category of so-called logical languages, which try to establish a strictly systematic and, well, logical grammar without unpredictable irregularities.
The most well-known one is [Loglan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loglan) with derivates [Lojban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lojban) and [Ceqli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceqli).
Another, indepedently developed logical language is [Ithkuil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ithkuil) with derivate [Ilaksh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ithkuil#Ilaksh).

What you are looking for might also be a philosophical language; however these usually put more focus on a systematic lexicon (using an elaborate ontology and as close as possible 1:1 mapping between form and meaning) than on grammar.
The closest possible candidate would probably be [Ars signorum](https://www.frathwiki.com/Ars_signorum).

For conlangs that attempt a strictly systematic composition of words and sentences from atomic parts, see also [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/20925/13238).

Answer (score 2):

You probably heard of a so-called *logical language*. Due to a split in the community, there are at least two of them named [Loglan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loglan) and [Lojban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lojban).