# Standardized and ambiguity-free language

Tags: semantics, grammar, sanskrit, constructed-language, esperanto

Is there exist a language (the natural or the constructed one) with a completely standardized and ambiguity-free rules, and which is suitable for the modern use?

I am wondering for a language which should be strict, logical, and ambiguity-free as the programming one.

By the word "rules" I mean grammar, word order, punctuation, and so on. Everything except pronunciation.

The languages with which I'm familiar (I'm native Russian with some practice in English) doesn't look as something what I'm searching for.

- There are a lot of weird things which doesn't have any sane logic behind them.
- There are some things that doesn't really solved. One example is the Oxford comma. Sometimes we need to use it to remove ambiguity, sometimes preserve it, and sometimes we will have ambiguity whatever.
- Some things are so complicated that even linguists have holy wars about them.
- Some things have too loose rules. One thing which is very different between Russian and English is that in Russian you can mix word order in a very free way. You may think it is cool, but actually it leads for a lot of problems.
- In English, we have compound nouns like "water tank capacity" which aren't ambiguity-free (this is successfully resolved in Russian).
- And so on.

Then I started to learn Esperanto. It is cool in some aspects, but it doesn't have standardized punctuation.

One man on the internet said that Sanskrit is the only language with a completely standardized rules, but he is Sanskrit teacher and can be biased. Also, I'm not sure that Sanskrit have words for the modern life, like "electricity" or "software".

May be German, Icelandic, Chinese, Latin? Something different?

Comment: For constructed language, you might find an answer here: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/21473/13238

Comment: Any language will work if it's simplified to remove ambiguities. An example is [Simplified Technical English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Technical_English), which is clear enough for Boeing to have built a [robust style checker for it](https://www.boeing.com/company/key-orgs/licensing/simplified-english-checker.page), which allowed them to save millions in translation fees for aircraft manuals; they're all in STE, all over the world.

Comment: I wonder if you started to incorporate Lobjan into your programming since this question was answered.

Comment: @jlawler, STE doesn't solve weird plurals, irregular verbs, inconsistent prefix usages etc. I'd really wanted to say that I `drawed` a bunch of `sheeps`. It's really something that matters for OCD people like me when you are writing programming code and _everything_ is unambiguous except naming things, actions, modifications, behaviours, and so on, the bits of a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you were perhaps looking for: 
[*Lojban*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lojban) (*ложбан*) is a conlang which is a syntactically unambiguous human language with logical and unambiguous structure and greater means of expression aimed at eliminating ambiguity in language. The name "Lojban" is a compound formed from loj and ban, which are short forms of logji (logic) and bangu (language).

Lojban is designed to express complex logical constructs precisely, it has no irregularities or ambiguities in spelling and grammar (although word derivation relies on arbitrary variant forms). This gives rise to high intelligibility for computer parsing. It is designed to be as culturally neutral as possible and allows highly systematic learning and use, compared to most natural languages. Also, it possesses an intricate system of indicators which effectively communicate contextual attitude or emotions. As for punctuation, it is actually not needed, since all the syntactic structure is expressed within the words, even question marks and exclamation points are not needed, although they still can be used.

Comment: It has no structural ambiguities, but it does embrace semantic ambiguity in certain areas, by design. Its _tanru_ (complex predicates) were originally referred to in English as "metaphors".

Comment: From what I read about Loglan and Lojban, the former seems to be better. Are there any specific reasons to choose the latter? (Yes, this question looks like something biased. It is.)

Comment: @jsv - I chose Lojban because as far as I know Loglan stopped being used and developed years ago, for example, the [official web-page of Loglan](http://www.loglan.org/) hasn't been updated since 2016, while Lojban is a thriving conlang, there's a [community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/lojban) working all the time on its development.